# How to solve UnboundedLocalError: local variable referrenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack-api

I know articles are existing for this similar issue. But I don't see a case of a global variable here, I have not used this as a global variable in code. So it has confused me and stuck for a while.

Function:

```
def slack(inform):
   
    env_name = libs.get_env_name()

    if env_name == 'ISPROD':
        web_hook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX'
    elif env_name == 'DEV':
        web_hook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX'
    msg = {'text':inform}
    requests.post(web_hook_url,data=json.dumps(msg))
```

web_hook_url is not declared globally anywhere outside this function. What else could be causing this?

Error says:

```
[ERROR] UnboundLocalError: local variable 'web_hook_url' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 402, in pull_data
    transfer_send(
  File "main.py", line 314, in transfer_send
    slack(pass_mess)
  File "main.py", line 111, in slack
    requests.post(web_hook_url,data=json.dumps(msg))
```

Comment: Why do you think `web_hook_url` is defined at that line?

Comment: could there be a better place for it, please let me know. I'll try that

Comment: You don't have an `else` to handle the situation when `env_name` is not one of the infinitely many values *other* than `ISPROD` and `DEV`.

Comment: (er, *is* one of the infinitely many...)

Comment: I don't understand then why are the errors kind of misleading :*(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add `print(env_name)`

```
def slack(inform):
   
    env_name = libs.get_env_name()
    print(env_name)
    if env_name == 'ISPROD':
        web_hook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX'
    elif env_name == 'DEV':
        web_hook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX'
    msg = {'text':inform}
    requests.post(web_hook_url,data=json.dumps(msg))
```

and see what value it is, because it's look like it has other value that you trying to check in if elif block

if you want just to avoid this error:

```
if env_name == 'ISPROD':
        web_hook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX'
elif env_name == 'DEV':
        web_hook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX'
else:
     web_hook_url = None
```

Comment: I tried passing values hardcoded way no luck there. :(

Comment: @Ashirwad.nivalkar if you set web_hook_url without if elif block, it would be fine or raising another error

Comment: I tried that, I came up with a multiplied number of errors, so went back to this.

Comment: @Ashirwad.nivalkar i can't check your requests and what is this "libs" module or something

Comment: @555Rushich ..... you were absolutely right as well .....Thank you
 I just couldnt print(envname) as it is inside a Lambda and terraform builts it on the fly